# Qt for python not working: Spyder not launching and matplotlib unable to plot

Tags: python, windows, qt, spyder

I am running Windows. I have Anaconda and several environments there, I use Spyder, and also Visual studio Code.
After updating packages (many, I cannot really tell which ones), spyder cannot be launched anymore. I get a window error with the following message.

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
> even though it was found. This application failed to start because no
> Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application
> may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: windows, direct2d, minimal, offscreen,
> webgl.

I can open visual studio code, but trying to show plots from `matplotlib` using `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` (that has qt as default plotter) it shows almost the same error on the console,

> QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x2844e951fa0) is not the
> object's thread (0x2844e952a40). Cannot move to target thread
> (0x2844e951fa0)
>
> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
> even though it was found. This application failed to start because no
> Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application
> may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: windows, direct2d, minimal, offscreen,
> webgl.

Qt is installed pyqt5 is installed in all the environments I have, and also in system's python.

I did reinstall all anaconda and didn't help. I also added the qt paths to the environment variables. But still does not work...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised I didn't find this before.
The solution in my case was simply to install [pyside6](https://pypi.org/project/PySide6/),

So, running

```
pip install PySide6
```

on my conda enviroment did the trick. I hope this helps someone.